# How to convert a little-endian UTF-16 unicode to a erlang string

Tags: unicode, erlang, odbc

I have a string value as aman which is printed as `<<97,0,109,0,97,0,110,0>>` and when I do:

```
A=<<97,0,109,0,97,0,110,0>>
erlang:binary_to_list(A)
```

I get `[97,0,109,0,97,0,110,0]`
But instead I need a string as "aman" or simply aman

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`unicode:characters_to_list/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_list-2), specifying the encoding of the binary in the second argument:

```
> A = <<97,0,109,0,97,0,110,0>>.
<<97,0,109,0,97,0,110,0>>
> unicode:characters_to_list(A, {utf16, little}).
"aman"
```